# How To Add Toast To Compiled App

Tags: android, toast

Is there any way to add toast to compiled app? I want to add a toast on app start.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No source code, no toast.**

To get source code from  apk -> retro-engineering !
There is tools like APK Decompiler that should help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm trying. retro-engineering decompiler>editor>compiler. Am I right?

Comment: You're right. Follow this way and then you may compile it with your toast !

Comment: I found MainActivity.smali file. I want to add toast but it not look like a java file. How can I add Toast to Main Activity?

Comment: .smali are parts of a java file. Easiest thing to do is to create a new blank project and then take parts of the code to your new project. This way you will have the source code.

Comment: I modified succesfully. Read some smali lessons. And I have a last question. Why I got -5 vote? I'm new ^^

Comment: Because this question has already been answered, so you may not searched by your side sufficiently. In adddition, Stack community like to have more details with formatted text. :)

Comment: Oh understood. But I didnt find more detail about my question :D And really Googled but i think with wrong keywords. My bad ^^

Answer (score 5):

just download apkeditor  !
then find a class u want 
now u can see  .smali code <3

now for Toast YOU shoud use this below code under a method oncreate :D

```
 const/4 v0, 0x1

    const-string v1, "inter your masge"

    invoke-static {p0, v1, v0}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->makeText(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;

    move-result-object v0

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V
```